# Wordpress layout select

Tags: wordpress

I am new with wordpress, so sorry for the basic question.

I generated my underscores (_s) wordpress theme named 'steeps', which has two custom layout css files in the 'layouts' directory.

These start with

```
/*
Theme Name: steeps
Layout: Content-Sidebar
*/
```

and

```
/*
Theme Name: steeps
Layout: Sidebar-Content
*/
```

I would have thought that the Layout: would cause wordpress to give me a selection somewhere for Content-Sidebar vs. Sidebar-Content [maybe vs. default], but for the life of me I can't find it.

Where is this selection, or how do I make it available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the developers of _s, there is no way to select the layout. See https://github.com/Automattic/_s/issues/407 , specifically https://github.com/Automattic/_s/issues/407#issuecomment-64483065

Answer (score 0):

I think the selection you search is on the right side of create a new post page

Comment: Thanks but I see the Template, which is a php file, but not the Layout which is a css file.

Comment: Ohh my mistake. As far as i know you cant change css files in acp

Comment: Just to be clear for anyone else who might answer this question, what I am trying to do is load a small css file in addition to the standard style.css. This appears to be the feature provided by underscores (_s) (and I assume wordpress, as part of the Layout: file attribute), but I don't know how it is applied.